# Limit of fraction of integer parts

Tags: calculus

I cant manage to justify $\lim_{n}$ $\frac{n}{\lceil n \delta \rceil}=\frac{1}{\delta}$ for integers $n$

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Iss tht the floor function there at denom. ?

Comment: @BabakS. cealing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the identity
\begin{align}
\lceil n\delta \rceil =\lfloor n \delta \rfloor+1=n\delta+1-\{n\delta\}
\end{align}
where $0\le\{n\delta\}<1$, then it follows
\begin{align}
\frac{n}{\lceil n\delta \rceil}= \frac{n}{n\delta+1-\{n\delta\}}\rightarrow \frac{1}{\delta}
\end{align}
as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Edit: The method still works when $n\delta$ is a integer for infinitely many $n$.

Comment: Definitely the way to go

Comment: Actually, $\lceil x\rceil\le\lfloor x\rfloor +1$

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales True. I was assuming $n\delta$ not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Using

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{\lceil x\rceil}=1$$

we can apply the "squeeze" theorem to the following
\begin{eqnarray}
\lfloor n\delta\rfloor&\le& n\delta\le\lceil n\delta\rceil\\
\frac{\lfloor n\delta\rfloor}{\lceil n\delta\rceil}&\le&\frac{n\delta}{\lceil n\delta\rceil}\le1\\
\frac{1}{\delta}\cdot\frac{\lfloor n\delta\rfloor}{\lceil n\delta\rceil}&\le&\frac{n}{\lceil n\delta\rceil}\le\frac{1}{\delta}\\
\frac{1}{\delta}&\le&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{\lceil n\delta\rceil}\le\frac{1}{\delta}
\end{eqnarray}